# Is RMSProp compatible with online (stochastic) learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

Quick question : 
Is *RMSProp* optimizer compatible with online (stochastic, update weights every turn) learning ? All I can read of is about *RMSProp* being used with **mini-batch** or **full-batch** update, but none seems to **explicitely** state that online stochastic learning would be out of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very short answer: it is. You can use it with SGD. Example: http://www.erogol.com/comparison-sgd-vs-momentum-vs-rmsprop-vs-momentumrmsprop/